# Is there a rich theory of sets with $3$ or more binary operations satisfying certain conditions?

Tags: abstract-algebra, reference-request

The definition of a group is a set $X$ equipped with a binary operation $\ast: X \to X$ obeying certain conditions. Studying these objects allows us to deduce a remarkable amount of theory - group theory.

The definition of a ring or a field is a set $X$ equipped with two binary operations $+: X \to X$ and $\times: X \to X$ obeying certain conditions. Again, applying such conditions leads to rich theories of these objects.

What about a set equipped with three (or more) binary operations? Are there certain conditions we can impose on them that allows us to develop a rich theory?

If not, why not? If so, what are these operations and/or conditions analogous to? In the case of groups the conditions capture the essence of how certain mathematical objects are symmetrical, for example, and in the case of rings and fields, they are analogous to how addition and multiplication behave on mathematical objects such as numbers, matrices, etc, hence why they are typically named $+$ and $\times$.

Further, if such objects have been studied, can someone give me a reference to what they are called and/or who has written about them and where?

Comment: One obstruction to getting a rich theory would be the large number of axioms needed to specify how each pair of operations interact with each other, so roughly $\frac{n(n-1)}{2}$ axioms for $n$ binary operations. [quadratic in $n$]  Not to mention interactions between interactions, etc.  With 2 it's fairly straightforward.

Comment: In my (limited) experience, what is more common is operadic structures or operations of arbitrary arity, like Massey products in the cohomology of a dga.

Comment: Algebras over a field have three operations: a sum, a product by scalars (technically not a binary operation on X) and a product, and they have a very rich theory.

Comment: These are **answers** (or at least attempts) to the question, not just a comment. Comments should only be used to **clarify**, not answer the question. See **[How do comments work](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19756/how-do-comments-work)** for more information. Therefore, please post your answer as an answer. This brings extra visibility to the answer und puts the question off the unanswered list. Also notice that comments are not indexed by the full text search, don't have any revision history, can only be edited for 5 minutes and allow only limited markup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A lattice-ordered group or $\ell$-group has three binary operations: $\vee$, $\wedge$, and $\cdot$.

A lattice-ordered ring or $\ell$-ring has four binary operations: $\vee$, $\wedge$, $+$, and $\times$.